# Comparing values in two list and updating it into the dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary with below values, which consists airline **code** and their **perror** number.

```
peq = {
  'sg':{'code':9, 'perror':0},
  '6e':{'code':17, 'perror':0},
  'g8':{'code':25, 'perror':0},
  'i7':{'code':33, 'perror':0},
  '9h':{'code':41, 'perror':0},
  'it':{'code':49, 'perror':0},
  'ic':{'code':57, 'perror':0},
  '9w':{'code':65, 'perror':0},
  's2':{'code':73, 'perror':0},
  'ai':{'code':81, 'perror':0}
}
```

I have a variable which is shown below. **perrors** consists of error code and **acode** is the airlines code similar to the one which is mentioned above in **peq** dictionary

```
perrors = ['0', '281', '2', '16', '0', '0', '2', '0', '0', '1']
acode = [41, 65, 17, 81, 73, 57, 9, 49, 33, 25]
```

I have then zipped the above two list in dictionary

```
>>> ic = dict(zip(acode,perrors))
>>> ic
{65: '281', 25: '1', 49: '0', 81: '16', 41: '0', 17: '2', 9: '2', 73: '0', 57: '0', 33: '0'}
>>>
```

Now what I am actually trying to solve is to update **perror** mentioned in the **peq** dictionary by comparing the ic code (on the left) with the value in the right in peq "perror".

Sorry if i am not being clear but in a nutshell I want to update all the values of `perror` mentioned in the `peq` dictionary with the values on its right mentioned in the `ic` dictionary but first it needs to do comparison whether the code exist in `peq` and if it does then update its `perror` (`peq` dictionary) with `ic` value.

Comment: A) What have you tried? B) Why does perror fluctuate from int to float datatype?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate the `dict` and use the proper key from the zipped `list`:

```
import pprint

peq = {
'sg':{'code':9, 'perror':0},
'6e':{'code':17, 'perror':0},
'g8':{'code':25, 'perror':0},
'i7':{'code':33, 'perror':0},
'9h':{'code':41, 'perror':0},
'it':{'code':49, 'perror':0},
'ic':{'code':57, 'perror':0},
'9w':{'code':65, 'perror':0},
's2':{'code':73, 'perror':0},
'ai':{'code':81, 'perror':0}
}

perrors = ['0', '281', '2', '16', '0', '0', '2', '0', '0', '1']
acode = [41, 65, 17, 81, 73, 57, 9, 49, 33, 25]    
ic = dict(zip(acode,perrors))

for k, v in peq.items():
    try:
        v['perror'] = ic[v['code']]
    except KeyError:
        print 'failed to find code {} at ic zip'.format(v['code'])

pprint.pprint(peq)
```

Output:

```
{'6e': {'code': 17, 'perror': '2'},
 '9h': {'code': 41, 'perror': '0'},
 '9w': {'code': 65, 'perror': '281'},
 'ai': {'code': 81, 'perror': '16'},
 'g8': {'code': 25, 'perror': '1'},
 'i7': {'code': 33, 'perror': '0'},
 'ic': {'code': 57, 'perror': '0'},
 'it': {'code': 49, 'perror': '0'},
 's2': {'code': 73, 'perror': '0'},
 'sg': {'code': 9, 'perror': '2'}}
```

Comment: Hi @Kobi K, although your solution worked but i quite did not understood it properly. Without doing any membership test we are inserting values in peq